# MariaDB has both `authentication_string` and `Password` field in the `mysql.user` table

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, mariadb

I installed MariaDB which is the default package for MySQL in Arch (Antergos) Linux. I also did a `mysql_secure_installation` and changed the `root` password. After that I installed PHPMyAdmin and tried to log in to the dashboard but was not able to do so using the `root` account because of apparent 'wrong password' which felt weird because I definitely knew what the password was. Multiple attempts failed. After a while I got fed up and tried to change the password using the `--skip-grant-tables` method. Now since my version of MySQL was recent where instead of `Password` field, you now have `authentication_string`. So I changed the `authentication_string` to a new `PASSWORD('my-new-password')` and then tried to log in again but that too didn't work. So then I again did the same method but this time I changed the `Password` field instead of the `authentication_string` and this time it worked! I felt a little suspicious about it so then I logged in to the `mysql` database and checked the `user` table and to my surprise there were both `authentication_string` and `Password` field. Now the question is whether or not this is intentional or just a mistake from MariaDB?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pam-authentication-plugin/ and/or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/pluggable-authentication.html ?

Answer (score 0):

The password column is deprecated and MariaDB is removing the password column in its 10.4 server version: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12715